change the way xfce4 desktops are saving the configuration of displays
I'm using ltsp to use the same linux-os(mostly xfce4 desktops on ubuntu and debian) on different workstations mostly with more than one monitor. The easiest way to configure the monitors(position, main monitor,resolution and so on) is using the display-GUI in the settings of xfce4. All these settings are saved by the system in a file (displays.xml) in the working user's home somewhere in the "/.config path". That is a working routine that's fine for a single workstation, but as soon as You start changing the places from one WS to the other, using the same os on the different place with different monitors, saving the settings in one file reaches its limits. Different monitors have different values to be saved in that file and if resetet, You overwrite the old values of the other place of work.
Allready tried:

There are ways to save these settings station orientated and not in userland by using the configuration of display-managers like lightdm. To do so a file called "greeter-setup-script is called" and that works fine for ubuntu, but debian fails in some monitor configuration and mixes up a correct use of the monitors.
Another way is to configure the monitors by the call of xrandr-settings defined in the "/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45x11-custom_xrandr-settings" startup-file during boot. Here also ubuntu is fine debian fails on some monitors.

So finally (because that works on all systems) the upper mentioned, defining way via the "displays.xml" file seems to be the best way. But I would need to change the handling of the operation system to read the display-setting station orientated instead of using a single file for all the stations.
To solve the problem I could use stand-alone-systems instead of using ltsp, but I don't want to loose the fortune of having one system on all these workstations with much less work in managing them on a single system-installation.
I tried to find information about the system use of displays.xml, but couldn't find anything according to solve my prob. I also tried to save the configuration in station-orientated names like "displays.[hostname].xml" and then copying this information into "displays.xml" during the boot by autostart-files in the userland, but this file seems to be specially protected by the system. So You can't do everyhting You want like with normal files. If You change it like my way, the system renews it with an empty file on top afterwards.
So some years of experiences as an operator, my linux-knowledge and the pool of new ideas end here . . .
. . . expert help is wanted (pls. try it a way I can dig it ;-)
thank You for Ur attention
regards
jori
